# Errors in installing netcore with cabal-install

Tags: linux, haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I tried the following command as was instructed:

```
cabal install netcore
```

The errors were as follows:

```
rmichael@node:~/netcore$ cabal install netcore --force-reinstalls --reinstall
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: netcore-1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: network (dependency of netcore-1.0.0)
rejecting: network-2.6.0.2/installed-9fc..., 2.6.0.2, 2.6.0.1, 2.6.0.0,
2.5.0.0, 2.4.2.3, 2.4.2.2, 2.4.2.1, 2.4.2.0, 2.4.1.2, 2.4.1.1, 2.4.1.0,
2.4.0.1, 2.4.0.0 (conflict: netcore => network==2.3.*)
trying: network-2.3.2.0
next goal: unix (dependency of network-2.3.2.0)
rejecting: unix-2.7.0.1/installed-f86... (conflict: unix =>
bytestring==0.10.4.0/installed-d6f..., netcore => bytestring==0.9.*)
trying: unix-2.7.1.0
next goal: parsec (dependency of netcore-1.0.0)
rejecting: parsec-3.1.9/installed-3e8... (package is broken)
trying: parsec-3.1.9
next goal: text (dependency of parsec-3.1.9)
rejecting: text-1.2.0.4/installed-3df... (conflict: text =>
bytestring==0.10.6.0/installed-768..., netcore => bytestring==0.9.*)
trying: text-1.2.0.4
next goal: bytestring (dependency of netcore-1.0.0)
rejecting: bytestring-0.10.6.0/installed-768..., 0.10.4.0/installed-d6f...,
0.10.6.0, 0.10.4.1, 0.10.4.0, 0.10.2.0, 0.10.0.2, 0.10.0.1, 0.10.0.0
(conflict: netcore => bytestring==0.9.*)
rejecting: bytestring-0.9.2.1, 0.9.2.0 (conflict: text =>
bytestring>=0.10.4.0)
rejecting: bytestring-0.9.1.10, 0.9.1.9, 0.9.1.8, 0.9.1.7, 0.9.1.6, 0.9.1.5,
0.9.1.4, 0.9.1.3, 0.9.1.2, 0.9.1.1, 0.9.1.0, 0.9.0.4, 0.9.0.3, 0.9.0.2,
0.9.0.1, 0.9 (conflict: unix => bytestring>=0.9.2 && <0.11)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
rmichael@node:~/netcore$
```

I'm not able to decipher what my next course of action should be from these messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.: My end objective is to get [FlowLog](https://github.com/tnelson/FlowLog) up and running. I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 system here.

Comment: Your first course of action should probably always be to build in a sandbox. The problem is that the selected version of netcore requires `bytestring==0.9.*` and the selected version of text requires `bytestring>=0.10.4.0` - obviously incompatible. I think that the constraint introduced by netcore is much too tight, but you can try installing with `--constraint='bytestring==0.9.*'`.

Comment: I tried and failed a bit on this too with `--dry-run`. I had a silly idea of trying to fix packages at the versions that were new back in 2012 when `netcore` was uploaded. I crashed hard into a problem you're also bound to hit: the `binary` versions required by `netcore` don't work with modern GHC. With the strange mixture of dependencies with too strict constraints and dependencies with no constraints at all, I suspect this package has thoroughly bitrotted.

Comment: @user2407038: Thanks! I'll be sure to try that first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to install old packages surrounding an old package I'm trying to build, I find it much more reasonable to go and bump all its version deps (or do so automatically with `--allow-newer`) then go do the janitorial work to fix the (minor) breakages introduced therein. Typically there are only a few things that need fixing, although they might need to be fixed a number of places. And the end result is an updated version of the package you can send back to the authors and ask them to put up on hackage!